# Is there a version of Whitney Embedding's theorem for infinite dimensional?

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Since we have a infinte dimensional version of Sard's Theorem and Transversality's theorem, I was thinking that this question is reasonable.  Any reference would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Separable, metrizable Frechet manifolds are all open subsets of the separable Hilbert space.